# How to force N[ ] to output the real value (or all values) for negative cube roots

Tags: equation-solving, complex, numerical-value

Evaluating N[(-1)^(1/3)] returns 0.5 + 0.866i in my v12.0 notebook. Of course, the equation x^3 = -1 has three distinct solutions for x. Is there a global (or local) option that will force Mathematica to output the real solution in favor of the complex ones? In this case, simply -1?

Further to this, if my notebook defaults to evaluating (-1)^(1/3) to a complex number, can I assume that Mathematica is doing the same when plotting complicated expressions with cube roots? Namely that some areas of the plot may appear imaginary when in fact there is a real solution available?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen `Surd[]`?

Comment: Hi J. M.  

Surd[(-1),3] would give the desired result here, but for a complicated expression where some terms contain a cube root, it would be very cumbersome to have to manually call Surd[ ] for the terms which happen to be cube roots.

Comment: Can you give an example where you think making this replacement is difficult? That said, the *principal branch* of $\sqrt[3]{z}$ is generally agreed on, but you can always premultiply such radicals with `Exp[2 I π/3]` if need be.

Comment: Perhaps more detail is required. I am examining a function that has an additive term like: 

$f(x)=(- x^3 + 5 x + (-2 + \sqrt{-27 x^2 + 10 x^3 - 48 x + 115}))^{1/3}$

The question is, for what values of x is this function real? If one simply plots the function, it will appear to be real on the interval (0,1.9). The term under the square root however, is real on (0,1.9) AND when $x>3$. Suppose $x = 4$, then the function reduces to:

$f(4)=(\sqrt{131}-46)^{1/3}$

Comment: This clearly CAN be real and evaluate to $f(4)\sim 3.2$, if one chooses the correct branch, but N[(-46 + Sqrt[131])^(1/3)] does not give the real value, nor does the plot, which assumes the function is imaginary when $x>3$.

As I am examining many plots visually that contain this term, it is important to get Mathematica to display the real branch (when $x>3$) in my plots.

Comment: Perhaps you can refocus on asking for a way to convert a complicated expression containing `Power[w, 1/3]` into `Surd[w, 3]`, if so.